# How can I change nanvalues in a pdDataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of values that need to be in place of this NaNs how can I change them?

[image: DF]

Comment: What do you mean exactly, with the list of values you want to replace the nans with, do you have a value for each nan that you want to replace?

Comment: Do you want to replace nans only in that one row? And are all values in that row nans?

Comment: yes i have a list that i want to replace the nans with. The nuns are just like the bottom 21 values of a column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
        [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]
    ],
    columns=list("ABCD")
)

print("Before:")
print(df)

replace_A = [9, 10, 11]
df["A"].loc[df["A"].isna()] = replace_A
print("After:")
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
Before:
     A    B   C    D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0.0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4.0
After:
      A    B   C    D
0   9.0  2.0 NaN  0.0
1   3.0  4.0 NaN  1.0
2  10.0  NaN NaN  NaN
3  11.0  3.0 NaN  4.0
```

Comment: yes but i need it to be replaced with this list ['Australian Grand Prix', 'Bahrain Grand Prix', 'Chinese Grand Prix', 'Azerbaijan Grand Prix', 'Spanish Grand Prix', 'Monaco Grand Prix', 'Canadian Grand Prix', 'French Grand Prix', 'Austrian Grand Prix', 'British Grand Prix', 'German Grand Prix', 'Hungarian Grand Prix', 'Belgian Grand Prix', 'Italian Grand Prix', 'Singapore Grand Prix', 'Russian Grand Prix', 'Japanese Grand Prix', 'United States Grand Prix', 'Mexican Grand Prix', 'Brazilian Grand Prix', 'Abu Dhabi Grand Prix']

Comment: that could work but then i would lose all the other values i have in the  column_with_nans that i need, it would be nice if there is away just to add values from the list in the columns where there is NaN values

Comment: Now I understand, I updated the example.